# Get the date expired in 60 day using Laravel

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to get the `date_fin_contrat` which will be expired in 60 days.

So I'm using the following formula:

```
date_fin_contrat-60 <= current_date
```

So in Laravel I'm using the following code:

```
$contrats_en_cours = Contrat::where('contrats.actif', 1)
    ->join('projets_castings', 'contrats.id_contrat', '=', 'projets_castings.id_contrat')
    ->leftjoin('projets', 'projets.id_projet', '=', 'projets_castings.id_projet')
    ->leftjoin('castings', 'contrats.id_casting', 'castings.id_casting')
    ->whereDate('contrats.date_fin_contrat', '-', 60, '<=', Carbon::today())
    ->get();
```

For example: Current date is `09-08-2021` and `date_fin_contrat` is `09-10-2021` I should get this row.

But I get nothing, is there something wrong with my query?

If you have any idea please help.

Comment: First of all, please AVOID using a lot of `joins` like that, it is totally solvable using relationships... for example `Contract::where('actif', true)->projets()->castings()->get()`. You would still need to add the `where` condition for contract, but still, way more readable.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used laravel whereDate function but you can do it this way simply

date_fin_contract = "09-10-2021"

```
$today_date = Carbon::now()->addDays(60)->toDateTimeString();
```

in where clause you can simpley check

```
where('date_fin_contract', '<=', $today_date);
```

`<=` represent contract is not expired

`>=` reprsent contract is expired

Comment: I think it would be more `>` than `>=` concerning the expired contracts. In general, the contract is still in force the last day.

Comment: Yes if contract is decided to be valid till last day, then `>=` should be replaced with `>`